# .htaccess URL Rewrite skipping the other /

Tags: regex, .htaccess, expression

I have the following code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^thumbnail/(.*).png thumbnail.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

And what that does is it turns

```
http://mydomain.com/thumbnail.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F
```

Into

```
http://www.mydomain.com/thumbnail/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F.png
```

But when I `echo` out the `url` variable in the `thumbnail.php` file it returns

`http:/www.example.com/` NOT `http://www.example.com/`

Where did the other `/` go?

Comment: you mean it turns `.../thumbnail/...` into `.../thumbnail.php?url=...`, not the other way around?

Comment: and you may want to replace `^thumbnail/(.*).png` by `^thumbnail/(.*)\.png` (`.png` -> `\.png`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `http://www.example.com/` is part of the URI path (as opposed to being part of the query string), apache automatically normalizes the path, thus removing multiple consecutive slashes. For example, if you tried to go to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/thumbnail/foo//////////////bar.png
```

And then print out the value of `url`, you'd get `foo/bar.png` because before the URI even gets to mod_rewrite in the processing pipeline, the extra slashes are cleaned out.

Alternatively, you could remove the `http://` part and add that in the rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^thumbnail/(.*).png thumbnail.php?url=http://$1 [NC]
```

Then your url would just be:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/thumbnail/www.example.com%2F.png
```

And when you print out the value of `url`, you'd get `http://www.example.com/.png`